# Detect value from a AR dice face swift

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have used ARkit and Scenekit to display a dice model when a horizontal plane is detected. I want to detect the value displayed on the dice after it is rolled, so that any other gaming logic can be implemented. How to identify the number of dots getting displayed in the AR dice?

```
        override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //1. Get The Current Touch Point
        guard let currentTouchPoint = touches.first?.location(in: sceneView) else {
            return
        }
         //2. Get The Next Feature Point Etc
            guard let hitTest = sceneView.hitTest(currentTouchPoint, types: .existingPlane).first else { return }
        //3. Convert To World Coordinates
        let worldTransform = hitTest.worldTransform
        
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/diceCollada.scn")
        if let diceNode = scene?.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Dice", recursively: true) {
            diceNode.position = SCNVector3(worldTransform.columns.3.x, worldTransform.columns.3.y + diceNode.boundingSphere.radius, worldTransform.columns.3.z)
            sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(diceNode)
            roll(dice: diceNode)
        }
        //4. Set The New Position
        let newPosition = SCNVector3(worldTransform.columns.3.x, worldTransform.columns.3.y, worldTransform.columns.3.z)
        dice.simdPosition = SIMD3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, newPosition.z)        
    }
```

[image: App screenshot display dice]

Answer (score 0):

A pretty easy way, add 6 invisible SUB-nodes - name them 1,2,3.4.. - position them on each edge, right in the center.  After the roll, the node with the highest Y value (assuming Y is up), is your answer.  6 compares, highest Y axis = name of node.

Edit request...
Create an edge1Node = SCNBox (small size), set its position.  You'll have to experiment because I don't know the size of your objects, but maybe start with X - 1, y=0, z=0 until you see it.  This is your offset from your dice node, so add diceNodeName.addChild(edge1Node).  Now you have a node that will stay associated to your diceNode even if it rotates or moves, so just resize and move it until it gets on the edge of your cube - technically it doesn't even have to be perfect - no one is going to see it anyway, it's just a differentiator between sides.  That's 1 done, do the other 5 - now all 6 subnodes move together with your dice node - then it's easy to see which one is higher than the others.

Comment: Can you pls say how can I add a node on each edge?. I tried adding an empty node on each edge in the .scn file and printed the position.y value. It's displaying their position values from the .scn file.